# Hibernate Second Level Caching Problems

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, ehcache

I am trying to enable second level caching in my java spring book API. The application runs perfectly but unit tests are failing on this error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method org.hibernate.cache.internal.DefaultCacheKeysFactory.createEntityKey(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionFactoryI
```

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>1.4.195</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
 ...
</dependencies>
```

The application.properties for tests:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

Comment: Have you verified that your application is using the same version of `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` as your `hibernate-ehcache`?